# element.loader.split is not a function in webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Her is my webpack.config.js and i am getting this error

> element.loader.split is not a function

i also changed loader to loaders after searching for its answer but it's still not working

```
    const postcssPlugins = [
  require('postcss-cssnext')(),
  require('postcss-modules-values')
];

const scssLoader = [
  { loader: 'style-loader' },
  { loader: 'css-loader' },
  { loader: 'sass-loader' }
];

const postcssLoader = [
  { loader: 'style-loader' },
  { loader: 'css-loader', options: { modules: true } },
  { loader: 'postcss-loader', options: { plugins: () => [...postcssPlugins] } }
];

var path = require('path');

var config = {
   entry: './todoApp.js',

   output: {
      path:'./',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },

   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 9191
   },

   module: {

      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',

            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         },
           {
             test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
             loader: scssLoader,
             include: [__dirname]
           },
           { test: /\.css$/,
             loader: postcssLoader,
             include: [__dirname]
           }
      ]
   }
}

module.exports = config;
```

I am not able to find where the error is
Please guide!

Comment: please could you share your package.json. Could be good to know the webpack version

Comment: Hi Jose its 1.13.3

Answer (score 1):

Try to change loader by loaders:

```
   {
     test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
     loaders: scssLoader,
     include: [__dirname]
   },
   { test: /\.css$/,
     loaders: postcssLoader,
     include: [__dirname]
   }
```

Comment: no it infact leads to an another error,  cannot read property replace of undefined

Comment: that should be loaders, maybe you have more than one error... check the official documentation https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/

Comment: Because you are using webpack 1.xx please, use this documentation: http://webpack.github.io/docs/using-loaders.html#what-are-loaders ...  write loaders in one line, instead of being objects: { test: /\.png$/, loader: "url-loader?mimetype=image/png" }